# A* Search Implementation

Tags: java, search, a-star

I am trying to implement the A* Search algorithm in Java to find the path for a given maze. The maze has a start and goal state and may contain obstacles.

Here is my code for solving a given maze:

```
  public Solver(Maze maze) 
  {

  explored = new HashSet<Square>(); // Set of squares that A* has investigated
  path = new ArrayList<Square>(); // List of squares to the goal
  Square currentSquare = maze.getStart();
  Square goalSquare = maze.getGoal();

  while (currentSquare.equals(goalSquare) != true)
  {
      System.out.println("Im here");


      // Calculate each direction from the current node
      Square left = new Square(currentSquare.getRow(), currentSquare.getColumn()         - 1);
      Square right = new Square(currentSquare.getRow(), currentSquare.getColumn() + 1);
      Square top = new Square(currentSquare.getRow() - 1, currentSquare.getColumn());
      Square bottom = new Square(currentSquare.getRow() + 1, currentSquare.getColumn());

      // Check if each direction is blocked. If it is, we cant go there.
      List<Square> possibilities = new ArrayList<Square>();

      if (maze.isBlocked(left) != true && path.contains(left) != true)
      {
          possibilities.add(left);
      }
      if (maze.isBlocked(right) != true && path.contains(right) != true)
      {
          possibilities.add(right);
      }
      if (maze.isBlocked(top) != true && path.contains(top) != true)
      {
          possibilities.add(top);
      }
      if (maze.isBlocked(bottom) != true && path.contains(bottom) != true)
      {
          possibilities.add(bottom);
      }

      // find which square we should go to next
      Square choice = currentSquare;
      int choicegx =  1000;//path.size();
      int choicehx = 1000;//Math.abs(goalSquare.getRow() - choice.getRow()) + Math.abs(goalSquare.getColumn() - choice.getColumn());
      int choicefx = 1000;//choicegx + choicehx;
      for (Square possibility : possibilities)
      {
          int fx = 0;
          int gx = 0;
          int hx = 0;

          // Calculate gx (distance traveled)
          gx = path.size();

          // Calculate hx (Manhatten distance)
          hx = Math.abs(goalSquare.getRow() - possibility.getRow()) + Math.abs(goalSquare.getColumn() - possibility.getColumn());

          // Calculate fx
          fx = gx + hx;

          if (fx < choicefx)
          { // Possibility is a better choice based on fx
              choicefx = fx;
              choicehx = hx;
              choicegx = gx;
              choice = possibility;
              if (choice.equals(goalSquare) != true && choice.equals(maze.getStart()) != true)
              {
                  explored.add(choice);
              }
          }
          else if (fx == choicefx)
          { // Squares are tied based on fx
              if (hx < choicehx)
              { // Possibility is better based on hx
                  choicefx = fx;
                  choicehx = hx;
                  choicegx = gx;
                  choice = possibility;
                  if (choice.equals(goalSquare) != true && choice.equals(maze.getStart()) != true)
                  {
                      explored.add(choice);
                  }
              }
              else if (hx == choicehx)
              { // Squares are tied based on hx
                  if (possibility.getRow() < choice.getRow())
                  {// Possibility is better based on row
                      choicefx = fx;
                      choicehx = hx;
                      choicegx = gx;
                      choice = possibility;
                      if (choice.equals(goalSquare) != true && choice.equals(maze.getStart()) != true)
                      {
                          explored.add(choice);
                      }
                  }
                  else if (possibility.getRow() == choice.getRow())
                  { // Squares are tied based on row
                      if (possibility.getColumn() < choice.getColumn())
                      { // Squares are tied based on column
                          choicefx = fx;
                          choicehx = hx;
                          choicegx = gx;
                          choice = possibility;
                          if (choice.equals(goalSquare) != true && choice.equals(maze.getStart()) != true)
                          {
                              explored.add(choice);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      // Move to the square we have chosen and add to path
      currentSquare = choice;
      if (currentSquare.equals(goalSquare) != true)
      {
          path.add(currentSquare);
      }

  }
}
```

I'm trying to decide a better way of designing this section:

```
Square choice = currentSquare;
      int choicegx =  1000;//path.size();
      int choicehx = 1000;//Math.abs(goalSquare.getRow() - choice.getRow()) +     Math.abs(goalSquare.getColumn() - choice.getColumn());
      int choicefx = 1000;//choicegx + choicehx;
```

In this section I determine the initial fx before looking through my choices of squares to take. Initially, I had been using my current node's fx to set these values. However, I then get into an issue of the search never exploring nodes that are worse then the current node. I want to always be making progress and never halting at a node that isn't the goal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [Priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). It's a structure used for "scheduling" visits of nodes, that you haven't yet visited. When you visit a node, you can calculate `gx` for all the nodes that you can visit from the current node and then store the nodes in the priority queue, ordered by the `gx` value, so that the nodes with lowest `gx` are on top.

The next node to visit is then picked from the top of the queue, therefore it can be one of the current nodes, but it can also be an older node, if it has lower `gx` than any other nodes left. This way you can always explore the path, that is currently the most interesting.